# Adding a character at beginning and at the end of each line in a text

Tags: text-processing

I'm looking for a way to add a character at beginning and at the end of each line of a txt file. The file contains a list of http addresses and I'd like to add the character " without any space, at the beginning and at the end of each address.

Comment: Do you have some empty lines as well?

Comment: Hello @Kulfy there are any empty line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If python is not an option, you can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' file
```

Brief explaination:

- `-i`: in-place (edit files in place )
- `s/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/`: this replaces all the content that matches the regular expression delimited by the first two slashes (in this case `^\(.*\)$` matches each line and saves the content of the line in the `\1` group, which will be used during the replacement) with the corresponding one between the last two slashes (in this case `"\1"` adds the quotes at the beginning and at the end of the group saved before).

Comment: fyi you can avoid an explicit capture group in this case by using the special `&` replacement character: `sed 's/.*/"&"/'`

Answer (score 3):

Using [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```bsh
sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' filename
```

`^` denotes the starting of line and `$` ending of line.

If you want to overwrite the file, use `-i` option.

```bsh
sed -i 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use python for it.

Just copy paste this code in a file called `test.py` and run it using `python3`

```py
file = open("/PATH/temp.txt", "r")

text = file.readlines()
file.close()
text2 = []
for x in text:
    if x[-1] == '\n':
        text2.append('"' + x[:-1] + '"')
    else:
        text2.append('"' + x + '"')

for x in text2:
    print(x)

file = open("/PATH/temp.txt", "w")
for x in text2:
    file.write(x + '\n')

file.close()
```

Edit the first and fourthlast line with appropriate path to the txt file you want to edit.